# Falla agregar elemento ADO.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2017, ado.net, mysqlconnector

Acabo de descargar el **Visual Studio 2017**, tengo **XAMPP** también en la ultima versión, e igual el **Workbench 6.3**. Así mismo baje el `Connector/Net 8.0.11` para realizar la conexión.

Pero a la hora que intento agregar un elemento *ADO.NET entity data model* me sale un error que no me deja hacer nada.

[image: aquí elijo poner el ado.net]

[image: elijo el modelo]

[image: Pongo la base de datos la cual al probar la conexion me dice que es exitosa]

[image: Y me sale el error]

Aquí elijo el elemento ADO.NET.
 Pongo el modelo.
 Hago la conexión a la base de datos, la cual al probar la conexión me dice que es exitosa.
 Y al final me sale está falla.
Este es lo que dice en la falla, la verdad no se que más hacer, si tenga una versión erronea  del conector o de algo.

Excepción:

> System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como
>   instancia de un objeto.    en
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)    en
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.VsUtils.GetProviderManifestTokenConnected(IDbDependencyResolver
>   resolver, String providerInvariantName, String
>   providerConnectionString)    en
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Gui.WizardPageRuntimeConfig.OnDeactivate()
>   en Microsoft.WizardFramework.WizardPage.Deactivate()    en
>   Microsoft.WizardFramework.WizardForm.OnNext()    en
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry
>   tme)    en
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
>   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    en
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    en
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    en
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry
>   tme)    en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()

Comment: Pienso que lo primero es, verificar que el servicio de `MySql` este corriendo.

Comment: y quiero creer que instalaste mysql no?

Answer (score 0):

Antes de intentar agregar el modelo verifica que tienes conexión al `MYSQL`, cuando le das a nueva conexión y configuras todo aparece un botón abajo.

Comment: Si si he verificao que tenga la conexión, hasta le doy en probar conexión y me dice que todo bien